# Find some elements in a list by a vector in R

Tags: r

I have a text and some words to find in it.

example:

```
test = 'a sentence full of text'
search = c('a', 'sentence', 'error')
```

I'm using match, but it is giving an error...

match(search, test)

```
[1] NA NA NA
```

I want to obtain a index or an vector contain TRUE/FALSE about this words...

example:

```
[1] 1 2 (index)
```

or

```
[1] TRUE TRUE FALSE
```

Tks

Comment: I need a vector, not only one output =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this `sapply(search, grepl, test)`?

Comment: Tks, it was perfect!